# video editor i key wont set key frames

Tags: video-sequence-editor

Blender 2.8 will not set a video key frame location with i,I, l, L,\or|. I even changed the preference to another key. No luck. Also, my keyboard is working and I re installed Blender.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

In the VSE you use these buttons:

[image]

Or you can use the right-click menu:

[image]